# BodePlot to calculate the amplitude and phase at a specific frequency

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I have transfer function:

$W=\frac{1}{s+1}$

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[{{1/(s + 1)}}, s]
BodePlot[tf, {.01, 100}]
```

It is very simple to construct a Bode diagram, but how to calculate the amplitude and phase shift with the help of '*BodePlot*' at a selected frequency, for example $\omega=2\pi$, is not clear...

Will be glad to advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[{{1/(s + 1)}}, s];
freqs = {{π, 2 π}};

BodePlot[tf, {.01, 100}, Mesh -> Table[freqs, 2], 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution is good for charting. It was interesting for me to calculate the magnitude and phase for the selected frequency. Please see my solution. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249543/67019

Comment: That's what [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) does - compute the magnitude and phase at the selected frequency. Also see [`how to get the coordinates for points in a plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GetCoordinatesForPointsInAPlot.html).

Comment: well, ok, it's good solution too, why not :)

Answer (score 4):

An example:

```
ss = StateSpaceModel[{3 y''[t] - 2 y[t] == u[t] + u'[t]}, {y[t], y'[t]}, {u[t]}, y[t], t];
tf = TransferFunctionModel[ss, s];

points = {Log10@#,20*Log10@Abs@tf[\[ImaginaryJ] #][[1, 1]]} & /@ {0.1, 1, 10} // N;

BodePlot[ss, {0.01, 100}, ImageSize -> 300, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[points]}, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude"]
```

[image]

I have added the Phaseplot

```
pointsArg = {Log10@#,Arg@tf[\[ImaginaryJ] #][[1, 1]]*180/\[Pi]} & /@ {0.1, 1, 10} // N;

BodePlot[ss, {0.01, 100}, ImageSize -> 300, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[pointsArg]}, PlotLayout -> "Phase"]
```

[image]

Comment: @dtn Do the calculation as I demonstrated. Replace only tf with `1/(1+s)`.

Comment: Nice solution, thank you! See also my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution and using [Bode plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot)

```
fr = ReplaceAll[1/(s + 1), s -> Sqrt[-1] \[Omega]];

LogLinearPlot[20 Log10[Abs[fr]], {\[Omega], 0.001, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> All];

LogLinearPlot[Arg[fr], {\[Omega], 0.001, 100}, PlotRange -> Full];

\[Omega] = 2 Pi;

N[Abs[fr]];

N[Arg[fr]];
```